# PHP pages display as 404 on iis 8 with windows server 2012

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2012

Installed php on windows server 2012 and then went to command line and `php -i` everything displayed like it should. Then went into iis and created the handler mapping for `php via fast cgi` at the server level, checked to make sure that it was available in a site I created on the server, but when I navigate to mysite/test.php all I get is a 404. Checked the php error logs and there is nothing new.

Suggestions, Ideas?

Comment: Do you get a detailed message from IIS? Try this from the server machine if not and update with the actual 404 code (404.x).

Comment: @NathanC in IIS I went to error pages under error pages edit features click detailed error pages, restarted IIS and then re-navigated to a test.php page and all I get is the default 404 page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... figured it out, my firewall was directing requests on port 80 to an old server I had. The PHP page was not on that server which is why I was getting the 404 and when I enabled detail errors I was not getting new errors.